# Solve equation $y^{\prime\prime}+3y^\prime+2y=e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve equation $y^{\prime\prime}+3y^\prime+2y=e^x$ with initial conditions $y(0)=0,y^\prime(0)=3$

So I first found complementary solution using characteristic polynomial
$$r^2+3r+2=(r+2)(r+1)=0$$

$$y_c=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-2t}$$

But not able to find a particular solution

$y_p=(Ax+B)e^x$

$y_p^\prime= Axe^x+Ae^x+Be^x$

$y_p^{\prime\prime}=Axe^x +2Ae^x+Be^x$

But substituting this into the given equation I get

$$Axe^x +2Ae^x+Be^x+3Axe^x+3Ae^x+3Be^x+2Axe^x+2Be^x=6Axe^x+5Ae^x+6Be^x=e^x$$

I then get that $A=0$ and $B=\frac{1}{6}$ but these don't satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: You satisfy the initial conditions by adjusting $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: @amd So the particular solution doesnt have to satisfy the initial conditions?

Comment: Just try $Ae^t \implies A=1/6$ . >Don't mix variable t and x. Choose one .

Comment: Your guess for the particular was harder than it had to be. The inhomogeneous term was linearly independent from the homogeneous solutions, so you only had to guess $y_p = Ae^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing fine.

$y=c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{-2x}+\frac 16e^x$

$y'=-c_1e^{-x}-2c_2e^{-2x}+\frac 16e^x$

Setting $y=0$ and $y'=3$ at $x=0$ gives:

$0=c_1+c_2+\frac 16$

$3=-c_1-2c_2+\frac 16$

Solev to find $c_1$ and $c_2$

Answer (score 1):

You could have make life easier using from the start $y=z\,e^x$ 
$$y''+3y'+2y=e^x \implies z''+5 z'+6 z=1$$
Now, let $z=u+\frac 16$ makes
$$u''+5u'+6u=0\implies u=c_1 e^{-3 x}+c_2 e^{-2 x}\implies z=c_1 e^{-3 x}+c_2 e^{-2 x}+\frac 16 $$ making by the end
$$y=c_1 e^{-2 x}+c_2 e^{-x}+\frac{1}{6}e^x$$ and then apply the conditions just as @tomi did show in his/her answer to get $c_1$ and $c_2$.